# Laravel collection for loops and mappings

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I am trying to refactor my code, and remove a for loop.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $language) {
    $result[$language->{$key}] = $language->{$column};
}
```

This became:

```
$result = $data->map(function($language) use ($key, $column){
    return [$language->{$key} => $language->{$column}];
});
```

But now instead of:

```
[
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value"
]
```

I am getting

```
[
    {
        "key":"value"
    },
    {
        "key":"value"
    }
]
```

Why doesn't it map like an array?

Comment: what you expect is wrong format, also share some sample data , and live demo ?

Comment: Please refer this: https://adamwathan.me/2016/07/14/customizing-keys-when-mapping-collections/ Hope this helps you!

Comment: @Norgul I have posted my answer, please check it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this [URL](https://adamwathan.me/2016/07/14/customizing-keys-when-mapping-collections/)

For Example:

```
$emailLookup = $employees->reduce(function ($emailLookup, $employee) {
   $emailLookup[$employee['email']] = $employee['name'];
   return $emailLookup;
}, []);
```

Gives you result like:

```
const emailLookup = {
   'john@example.com': 'John',
   'jane@example.com': 'Jane',
   'dave@example.com': 'Dave',
};
```

In your case do like:

```
$result = $data->reduce(function($language, $a){
     $language[$a['any_you_want']] = $a['any_you_want'];
     return $language;
}, []);
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

For your simple use case, [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) is the method you're looking for. It will build a new collection using one column of an existing array. You can also pass in a second field that will be used to key the new collection.

So, in your case, the data column you're selecting is `$column`, and the column to use as the key for the new collection is `$key`. Your code would be:

```
$result = $data->pluck($column, $key);
```

This says "give me a collection of all of the `$column` data, and key it by the `$key` data".

If you want the plain array instead of the collection, just call `all()` on the result:

```
$result = $data->pluck($column, $key)->all();
```

If you need to "pluck" more than one column of data, you will need to use the `mapWithKeys()` method already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You probably needed to [`mapWithKeys`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-mapwithkeys):

```
$result = $data->mapWithKeys(function($language) use ($key, $column){
    return [$language->{$key} => $language->{$column}];
});
```

The method has been available since Laravel 5.3

According to the docs:

> The `mapWithKeys` method iterates through the collection and passes each value to the given callback. The callback should return an associative array containing a single key / value pair:

Answer (score -2):

Here in loop you need to use as key value pair

`$result = []; 
foreach ($data as $key => $language) { 
    $result[$key] = $language; 
}`